# can i not do - if nums[i] == nums[i+]: in python

Tags: list, traversal

I am new to programming and python. (ref to code below) - I am trying to compare the elements in a list to eliminate duplicates in adjacent numbers in the list (so that all numbers in the resulting list are unique). I actually dont hit the nested "if" statement because this code skips the internal if. However when i try it without the external if, I get an error:   File "list2.py", line 22, in remove_adjacent
    if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  x = len(nums)
  print x
  for i in enumerate(nums):
    if i < x-1:
      if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
        del nums[i] 
  return
```

Comment: Apologies- i am unable to even add the code snippet with the proper formatting. Am new to stackoverflow - apologies for the unindented code (but it was entered with the proper indentation of 2 spaces (where needed).

Comment: Do you mind post the complete code? e.g. What do you pass in as "nums"?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `for i in range(len(nums))`. `enumerate` returns key/value tuple - which is not integer, as error message says.